# SOLR searching issue in RAILS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, solr, indexing, sunspot-solr

We have a solr search implemented. We are encountering a situation and wish to tackle it as cleanly as possible.  We have a book that has an isbn number and it has a relation of isbn numbers in different bindings.  When we perform a solr search we would like the first instance of that book to show up and none of its related instances.  In other words show the first  occurrence in the search based on the relation and its own isbn number.  I know that sounds confusing but let me elaborate.

If I search for books and I get one that has a main isbn = 9781617840227 and related isbns = "9781617147197", "1617147192".  I do not want "9781617147197", "1617147192" to display only 9781617840227.

I have thought about doing a double search (which will not work due to paging) and also not displaying duplicated but will break paging.

Any help is greatly appreciated,

Comment: I solved my own issue.  I used solr grouping and limit to get the results that I wanted.  I added a method to the model I was searching on that would give me an id based on certain criteria which would be duplicated if similar.  Grouping on this prevented my dups.